# Get path of Windows Explorer window in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to be able to get the current open path of a Windows Explorer window from the window handle.
I found shell code but can't find anything in C++

Comment: `GetShellWindow` + `GetWindowThreadProcessId` + `OpenProcess` + `QueryFullProcessImageNameW` + `CloseHandle`

Comment: @RbMm That will get the path to the Shell process itself (ie, `explorer.exe`), not the path that a given Windows Explorer window is displaying to the user.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, i misunderstand question. you are right